# Java PayPal Integration

Tags: paypal

I'm new with PayPal and I've got a task on my current internship.
I need to integrate PayPal with a WebApp (Maven Project) but with some features. On the 'admin' page will be displayed a list of "potencial clients", then the admin will select one client and set some configurations. After setting those configurations the admin will need to request a payment from the potencial client, this is, the admin will set the number of installments and it's value (something like billing plan, I guess) sending a payment request to the potencial client's e-mail and then wait for it.

As told before I'm pretty new with webdev and online money transactions. I was trying to do this with SDK REST Paypal's API but it doesn't looks to be working as I did describ above.

So, anyone could give-me some idea how to do this on my Java web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me see if I can provide some detail here. It sounds like what you're going to need is a recurring billing system, so that can be done with billing plans and agreements.

The first step is to set up the billing plan. The plan essentially sets up the architecture of the subscription for your company, and you can subscribe many users to a single plan. For each user that you want to subscribe, you then set up a billing agreement for each of them, which binds them to the plan you created.

Here's some quickstart code to get you started:

- [Billing plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-plan/)
- [Billing agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/create-billing-agreement/)

Also, if you need setup and config help with setting up the SDK, take a look at the required steps on [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/).

Hope that helps